# Apache config mess up, shows main app on a subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl

Sorry, this may be really simple, I'm somewhat of a newbie.
I had a main websites along with a blog subdomain up both with ssl certificates and http redirected to https. I added a mail server on a mail subdomain and tried running certbot to set up a certificate and set up a http to https redirect. But now both my mail subdomain along with my main domain shows my main app. Any help would be appreciated.

my http apache config:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName armanpopat.co.uk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =armanpopat.co.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName  blog.armanpopat.co.uk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blog.armanpopat.co.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mail.armanpopat.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/roundcubemail/roundcubemail-1.4.9/

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube_access.log combined

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/roundcubemail/roundcubemail-1.4.9/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =armanpopat.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mail.armanpopat.co.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

https config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName armanpopat.co.uk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/arman/mysite/static
    <Directory /home/arman/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/arman/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>    

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/arman/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/arman/mysite python-home=/home/arman/mysite/VENV
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite




Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias mail.armanpopat.co.uk
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/armanpopat.co.uk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/armanpopat.co.uk/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName  blog.armanpopat.co.uk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/arman/Test/static
    <Directory /home/arman/Test/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/arman/Test/media
    <Directory /home/arman/Test/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/arman/Test/Test>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>    

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/arman/Test/Test/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess Test python-path=/home/arman/Test python-home=/home/arman/Test/VENV
    WSGIProcessGroup Test


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/armanpopat.co.uk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/armanpopat.co.uk/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mail.armanpopat.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/roundcubemail/roundcubemail-1.4.9/

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube_access.log combined

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/roundcubemail/roundcubemail-1.4.9/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/armanpopat.co.uk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/armanpopat.co.uk/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have set ServerAlias mail.armanpopat.co.uk in the first block and  ServerName armanpopat.co.uk . If you don't intend mail subdomain to match it you should remove and test.

Comment: Thanks mate, you solved my problem!

Comment: Great. I've added the answer for anybody landing on this question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to ServerAlias mail.armanpopat.co.uk in the first block and ServerName armanpopat.co.uk . Hence all mail subdomain requests match the first virtual host.
Once this is corrected it should work.